# Connect centroids horizontally and detect missing objects

Tags: matlab, image-processing, detection

The task is to connect the centroids that I have got using `regionprops` horizontally in rows and then predict missing objects.

Here is the image that I have:

[image: detect_boundaries_and_centroids]

This is what I want to achieve :
[image: Connected_centroids_horizontally]

All centroids within a certain y-coordinate range should be connected. After that I want to predict the missing objects. For example, there should be more objects/centroids present on the green line in the image above.

My code so far :

```
BW = rgb2gray(imread('noise_removal_single_25_cropped.png'));
props = regionprops(im2bw(BW), 'Centroid');
centroids = cat(1, props.Centroid);

[B,L] = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');
imshow(label2rgb(L, @jet, [.5 .5 .5]))
hold on
for k = 1:length(B)
   boundary = B{k};
   plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'w', 'LineWidth', 2)
end

plot(centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2), 'b*')
plot(centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2), 'k-')
```

The code connects all centroids vertically and I have no idea how to detect missing objects/centroids (maybe based on length of line)?

Comment: where do you connect the centroids vertically? I only see you draw boundaries and centroids in your code.
one way would be to find each points nearest neighbours. missing points will cause neighbours to have a bigger distance than usual. of course you have the advantage of knowing that your points are grouped horizontally https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that the rows are perfectly horizontal. It seems that you can easily cluster the points by ordinate, either knowing row separators in advance, or by analysis of the point density.

Take the median ordinate of every cluster and discard the outliers (those farther than a defined tolerance from the median).

Sort the inliers by abscissa. The gap lengths (or point count in a sliding window) will tell you about missing points.

If the rows aren't perfectly horizontal, it remains likely that you can cluster by ordinates and obtain good horizontal separators. In every cluster, use a robust line fitting algorithm that will perform outlier detection, and sort horizontally as before. You can also deskew (using the line equation), but given the small slope, this will make little difference.

Final remark: if all lines are parallel, you can perform skew detection collectively by finding the gravity centers (or medioids) of the clusters and translating the clusters to a common center, giving a single thick line.